# How to remove fingerprint stains from a computer mouse?

Tags: cleaning

how I can "gently" clean thumb and ring finger stains from semi white mouse, otherwise mouse remains white but this grey area where you rest thumb and ring finger is now pretty much brown...

I have tried "magic mushroom (not the one you eat), and fiber cloth with basic house general cleaner (just a small tip because don't want to get fluid inside mouse).

Its somekind rubber/plastic mixture I think (https://steelseries.com/gaming-mice/sensei-raw-frost-blue)

Comment: Are you sure the gray spots are dirt from your finger, and not just the surface getting worn off by contact?

Answer (score 1):

Isopropyl alcohol (also called isopropanol or dimethyl carbino) which should be available in any chemists/drug store, is an excellent cleaner.

Simply invert the bottle on a (woman's) face cleaning pad and wipe the surface. It's also great for cleaning the underside of mice getting rid of the gunge which builds up there.

Comment: @AJFaraday I don't get it. I answered the question, even got an upvote and you come along and demote everything. Please explain how answering the question is "Not a life hack".

Comment: Not all answers need to be lifehacks in order to be considered a good answer. The solution OP suggest has been known for its usage in electronics as a cleaner agent @AJFaraday

Answer (score 0):

If its not the surface being worn away, but simply dirt, some of it should have shifted when you used the household cleaner. If it wasn't touched at all by that, its likely its staining because the top surface is no longer intact from wear over time. If, though, some of the marking did shift, then take a dry cloth, spray a few times with an ammonia based cleaner (Mr. Muscle kitchen spray in UK), make sure the fluid is absorbed into the cloth by folding together the areas you've sprayed and pressing lightly together, open it up again and then rub the dirty areas with that. If it comes off straight away, wipe over with a damp cloth and dry it thoroughly, but you may have to repeat the procedure more than once - ammonia based cleaners are more efficient if you're able to actually spray the dirty area, which, in your case, you can't.

Comment: While not exactly the same cleaner, we have Mr. Clean.

Answer (score 0):

First, unplug the mouse or remove the batteries. Use a disinfectant wipe (not too damp) for the up- and downside of the mouse. Then use a dry microfiber cloth for any remaining stains.

Comment: That does not address his question at all. It's just a generic cleaning routine that doesn't consider this kind of discoloration.

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1**: Unplug your mouse from your computer and remove any batteries.

**Step 2:** Use a lightly dampened microfiber cloth to wipe away grime or dirt. Be careful not to get moisture into any openings.

**Step 3:** Using a dry microfiber cloth, remove any remaining moisture from your mouse.

**Step 4 (optional):** If there are loose particles stuck underneath the scroll wheel, turn the mouse upside down and roll the scroll wheel to help dislodge anything that may be stuck inside.

*For more disinfecting:*

**Step 1:** Unplug your mouse from your computer and remove any batteries.

**Step 2:** Wipe your mouse with disinfectant wipes. Make sure that the wipes aren't overly damp and that you squeeze out any excess liquid before wiping the mouse. Take care to avoid getting moisture into any openings.

**Step 3:** Then immediately wipe your mouse down with a lightly dampened microfiber cloth.

**Step 4:** Using a dry microfiber cloth, remove any remaining moisture from your mouse.

Comment: That does not address his question at all. It's just a generic cleaning routine that doesn't consider this kind of discoloration.

Comment: @JDługosz That answer is just like mine. Why didn't you complain about it?

Comment: or why didn't vote yours negatively as well? :P

Comment: @JDługosz did you try it?